# Django ValueError when A field is empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have a `ModelForm` which is like this :

**Forms.py :**

```
class send_to_evaluatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = send_to_evaluator
        exclude = ('Creater_UserID','mozo1_id','mozo2_id','mozo3_id','knowledge')
```

so the problem comes when i leave a field empty and submit to save it... but when everything is filled and nothin left empty the code runs ok.

**a part of my view :**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = send_to_evaluatorForm(request.POST)
        mozo3=request.POST.get('mozo3')
        mozo1=request.POST.get('mozo1')
        mozo2=request.POST.get('mozo2')
        if form.is_valid:
            obj = form.save()
```

the error happens because the form doesnt validate and while i was debugging it i noticed that a field is required

here is my model if you want to have a look...if i let nazar empty my form doesnt save it
**models.py:**

```
    mozo1_id = ForeignKey(topic1,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    mozo2_id = ForeignKey(topic2,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    mozo3_id = ForeignKey(topic3,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    nazar = TextField(verbose_name='point_of_view',max_length=4000)
    create_date = IntegerField(default=LibAPADateTime.get_persian_date_normalized(), blank=True, null=True)
    Creater_UserID = ForeignKey(Members,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    knowledge = ForeignKey(TblKnowledge,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: and your question is? Why nazar empty make form doesnt save?

Comment: yes exactly this is my problem

Comment: i think problem not in fiend nazar. TextField not required when call 
form.is_valid().
Can you try print all param of form and update question?

Comment: i fixed it in a another way...i also excluded nazar from form then gave the field a name and in view i get the name and save to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set
`nazar = TextField(verbose_name='point_of_view',max_length=4000, null=True, blank=True)`(do migrations) If you want form to be saved without using that field.